# Example creating a PostgreSQL XML data type

Tags: postgresql, xml

I am looking for an SQL example where a table is created in PostgreSQL which has a field with data type XML.

Comment: Quoting JS: "Downvoters: please provide comments. – Jon Skeet May 8 at 9:25"

Answer (score 0):

From [PostgreSQL XML Support wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/XML_Support):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
   ...,
   myfield xml,
   ...
   );
```